# How to accept multiple file types in swal sweetalert

Tags: javascript, vue.js, yii

I am using swal sweet alert in my vue.js application. I need to allow multiple file types. I have the code to allow image. But I dont know how to allow multiple file types like pdf, ppt & doc in addition to the images. here is my code.
Your help is very much appreciated.

```
swal({
      title: 'Select file',
      input: 'file',
      inputAttributes: {
        'accept': 'image/*',
        'aria-label': 'Upload the file'
     }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate your meme types by a comma `,` just like this:

```
swal({
  title: 'Select file',
  input: 'file',
  inputAttributes: {
    'accept': 'image/*,application/pdf,application/vnd.ms-powerpoint,application/msword',
    'aria-label': 'Upload your profile picture'
  }
})
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGENrg?&editable=true

You can find a list of meme types here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Comment: Thanks @Hammerbot. I tried by adding pdf like `'accept': 'image/*,application/pdf',` but it is now accepting other file types as well. this might probably an issue from other parts of my code. I will check& update